# Issue with transactions logic and error handling

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I am following a online tutorials for transactions honoring the ACID concept. I have these two tables:

```
-- Create Product table
CREATE TABLE Product
(
  ProductId INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  Price INT,
  Quantity INT
)
GO

-- Populate the Product Table with some test data
INSERT INTO Product VALUES(101, 'Laptop', 1234, 100)
INSERT INTO Product VALUES(102, 'Desktop', 3456, 150)
INSERT INTO Product VALUES(103, 'Tablet', 5678, 200)
INSERT INTO Product VALUES(104, 'Mobile', 7890, 250)
GO

-- Create ProductSales table
CREATE TABLE ProductSales
(
  ProductSalesId INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductId INT,
  QuantitySold INT
) 
GO
```

I have created a stored procedure with a transaction, where I supply the productId and the quantity to sell.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSellProduct
@ProductID INT,
@QuantityToSell INT
AS
BEGIN
  -- First we need to Check the stock available for the product we want to sell
  DECLARE @StockAvailable INT

  SELECT @StockAvailable = Quantity 
  FROM Product 
  WHERE ProductId = @ProductId

  -- We need to throw an error to the calling application 
  -- if the stock is less than the quantity we want to sell
  IF(@StockAvailable< @QuantityToSell)
  BEGIN
    Raiserror('Enough Stock is not available',16,1)
  END
  -- If enough stock is available
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
      -- We need to start the transaction
      BEGIN TRANSACTION

      -- First we need to reduce the quantity available
      UPDATE    Product SET 
          Quantity = (Quantity - @QuantityToSell)
      WHERE ProductID = @ProductID

      -- Calculate MAX ProductSalesId
      DECLARE @MaxProductSalesId INT
      SELECT    @MaxProductSalesId = CASE 
          WHEN  MAX(ProductSalesId) IS NULL THEN 0 
          ELSE MAX(ProductSalesId) 
          END 
      FROM  ProductSales

      -- Increment @MaxProductSalesId by 1, so we don't get a primary key violation
      Set @MaxProductSalesId = @MaxProductSalesId + 1

      -- We need to insert the quantity sold into the ProductSales table
      INSERT INTO ProductSales(ProductSalesId, ProductId, QuantitySold)
      VALUES(@MaxProductSalesId, @ProductId, @QuantityToSell)

      COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      SELECT    ERROR_NUMBER() as ErrorNumber,
          ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage,
          ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
          ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
          ERROR_SEVERITY() as ErrorSeverity,
          ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine
    END CATCH
  End
END

go

spSellProduct @ProductId=103, @QuantityToSell=300
```

I check if the quantity is less then the quantity to sell, then I generate a error.
If no errors are encountered then I begin a transaction.

Then I deduct quantity from the product table.
After that I increment the ProductSalesId in the productSales table and insert the new row with ProductId and QuantitySold.

If any errors occurred I try handle them in my catch batch and rollback the transaction.

So in my Product table for ProductId 103 which has 200 quantity in stock, and I exec the stored procedure the following way:

```
spSellProduct @ProductId=103, @QuantityToSell=300
```

No errors are generated and the transaction does not rollback when @QuantityToSell is larger then Quantity. In this case the quantity for ProductId is 200 and the quantity I am attempting to sell is 300.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your procedure code inside a try catch and inside it you should put the transaction. Try using the following code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSellProduct]
@ProductID INT,
@QuantityToSell INT
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
     BEGIN TRANSACTION 
          -- First we need to Check the stock available for the product we want to sell
          DECLARE @StockAvailable INT

          SELECT @StockAvailable = Quantity 
          FROM Product 
          WHERE ProductId = @ProductId

          -- We need to throw an error to the calling application 
          -- if the stock is less than the quantity we want to sell
          IF(@StockAvailable< @QuantityToSell)
          BEGIN
            Raiserror('Enough Stock is not available',16,1)
          END
          -- If enough stock is available
          ELSE
          BEGIN
               -- First we need to reduce the quantity available
              UPDATE    Product SET 
                  Quantity = (Quantity - @QuantityToSell)
              WHERE ProductID = @ProductID

              -- Calculate MAX ProductSalesId
              DECLARE @MaxProductSalesId INT
              SELECT    @MaxProductSalesId = CASE 
                  WHEN  MAX(ProductSalesId) IS NULL THEN 0 
                  ELSE MAX(ProductSalesId) 
                  END 
              FROM  ProductSales

              -- Increment @MaxProductSalesId by 1, so we don't get a primary key violation
              Set @MaxProductSalesId = @MaxProductSalesId + 1

              -- We need to insert the quantity sold into the ProductSales table
              INSERT INTO ProductSales(ProductSalesId, ProductId, QuantitySold)
              VALUES(@MaxProductSalesId, @ProductId, @QuantityToSell)
            END
        COMMIT TRANSACTION CHECKTR
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
      SELECT    ERROR_NUMBER() as ErrorNumber,
          ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage,
          ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
          ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
          ERROR_SEVERITY() as ErrorSeverity,
          ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that out, but I am still not getting the expected error that should occur when I try spSellProduct @ProductId=103, @QuantityToSell=300. This should generate a error as I only have 250 in quantity for ProductId in the Product table